# why onserverclick does not work in href in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, href

I have problem that onserverclick attribute does not work ,the method which assigned to it does not trigger.

```
    string strTr = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < adminuserlist.Count; i++)
        {
          strTr += string.Format("<tr id=\"tr\">" +
                                          "  <td>{0}</td> " +
                                          "  <td>{1}</td> " +
                                          "  <td>{2}</td> " +
                                          "  <td>{3}</td> " +
                                          "  <td>{4}</td> " +
                                          "  <td>{5}</td> " +
                                          "  <td>{6}</td> " +
                                          "<td class=\"col-lg-2\">" +
                                          " <a href=\"#\" id=" + i + 
              "runat=\"server\" onServerClick=\"MyFuncion_Click\"    
             class=\"table-icontoolbar\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-
             placement=\"top\" title=\"Edit\"> " +
                                          "          <img         
                               src=\"../images/icon-edit.png\"></a> " +
                                          "      <a href=\"#\"  
             runat=\"server\" onClick=\"bll();\"  
            onServerClick=\"MyFuncion_Click2\" class=\"table-icontoolbar\" 
            data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\"  
               title=\"Delete\">" +
                                          "          <img 
               src=\"../images/icon-delete.png\"></a>" +
                                          "  </td> " +
                                          " </tr>",   
          adminuserlist[i].AdminUserName, 
           adminuserlist[i].AdminUserPassword,
                                          adminuserlist[i].AdminUserEmail, 
              adminuserlist[i].AdminUserType, adminuserlist[i].IsActive,
                                          adminuserlist[i].isDeleted,      
                adminuserlist[i].CreatedOn);

tbodyAdminUserView.InnerHtml = strTr;
}
```

and this the function which should be triggered:

```
  public void MyFuncion_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {           
        Label1.Text = "vvvv";
   }
```

Comment: Don't add generate HTML in your code behind like that. It's messy, and you can't build server side controls that way.

Comment: Consider using `Repeater` control instead.

Comment: Adding `runat=\"server\"` to your html is not going to produce server-side ASP.NET controls - this attribute has no meaning to browser, and by the time the above code executes the markup has been long parsed.

Comment: if u want to generate post back, go for document.form[0].submit()